# Is it possible to hide the bottom tab bar upon a button press and then draw it up when necessary by a simple touch?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

Hey their fellow stack over flowers!

As the question states, is it possible to perform such a feat?

If possible how would you go about doing it?

So the situation we have here is that there is a drawer and on top of it lies the bottom tab bar which annoys the whole view of the screen. That's why we should find a way to hide it. Isn't it?

Here's what you've got:

[image]

What's required is, hiding the tab bar when clicking on the hamburger menu and taking it back up when you touch or press down the bottom tab area. Obviously, I went through other quality questions with qualities answers here. But nothing seems to provide a providence a least bit

Do you know any clever way to handle this?

THANKS!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using custom tabBar, you could use React.Context or some kind of global state to trigger hiding your tabBar when you press a button. I would "hide" my tabBar by rendering the tabBar as a transparent Pressable with a certain height that when you click on it, it will rerender the original tabBar. You could also use setTimeout to rehide it automatically.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I didn't even read it!

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!

I want the tab bar to disappear when a user clicks the hamburger menu

Can you give me some further guidance?